# Android room DAO interface does not work with inheritance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

```
interface Marker<T : BaseFoo> {
    fun getSpecialFoo(): List<T>
}

@Dao
interface FooDao: Marker<Foo> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :bar")
    fun get(bar: Int): List<Foo>

    @Transaction
    override fun getSpecialFoo(): List<Foo> {
        return get(1)
    }
}
```

This results in

> An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of the following annotations: Insert,Delete,Query,Update,RawQuery

However, `Marker` is not marked with `@Dao` and `FooDao` override `getSpecialFoo` already. Why does this error still show?

I need `Marker` because I need a generic DAO that has some methods. Is there a way to work around this?

The only way I can think of is marking the dao to `Any` and cast the type runtime or build a wrapper for the DAO.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya That was a typo when I type on StackOverflow. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like it is limitation of the Room library. You can work around it like the following.

```
@Dao
interface FooDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :bar")
    fun get(bar: Int): List<Foo>

    @Transaction
    fun getSpecialFoo(): List<Foo> {
        return get(1)
    }
}

fun FooDao.wrapper(): Marker<Foo> {
    return Wrapper(this)
}


private class Wrapper(private val dao: FooDao): Marker<Foo> {
    override fun getSpecialFoo() = dao.getSpecialFoo()
}
```

When you need it to be `Marker<Foo>`, you can `wrapper()` to create a wrapper which implement `Marker<Foo>` by the `dao`.

Comment: a work around solution, but not as clean as using `@JvmSuppressWildcards`

Answer (score 31):

You can solve it.

The issue is not in room restrictions, but in the kotlin implementation itself. You are using generic collection method, which by default is processed to `List<? extends T>` java implementation, but overridden method has `List<Foo>` return type. Room generator matches a method signature and can't find an implemented method with the same signature, so you get

> An **abstract** DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of
> the following annotations

The solution is just to annotate a method result type in the interface with `@JvmSuppressWildcards`:

`fun getSpecialFoo(): List<@JvmSuppressWildcards T>`

Comment: top best answer. i wouldn't to write a wrapper around a DAO if this is a straight and simple answer.

Comment: Tip: if your BaseDao has @Transaction annotated methods then you need to make your `ConcreteClassDao` not an interface, but an abstract class.

Comment: Note that if your non-Room DAO interface contains a `suspend fun foos(): List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Foo>`, then the generated Room DAO will show a lint error on the generated Java method:

`foos(Continuation<? super List<Foo>>)` in `com.example.FooDao_Impl` clashes with `foos(Continuation<? super List<? extends Foo>>)` in `com.example.FooDao`; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other.

This is likely not a problem. The Java `List<E>` is different from Kotlin's `List<out E>` (with suppressed wildcard) anyways. Please comment here, or answer if you think otherwise!